# 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run selenium in Lambda.

Exe (for linux) chrome driver is bundled with code.

I am getting an error:

> 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions.

And I don't know what is wrong.

Can some one help me?

How can I fix it?

It is working on my machine.

My start driver code is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/.chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And I am using python.

Driver is in same folder as main python script

Comment: how do you initiate the chrome driver? What language are you using?

Comment: I added code into my question